# Object.create vs .prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance, oojs

**(Please close IF duplicate)**

Given the following scenario:

```
function Person(first, last) {
  this.name = {
    first,
    last
  };
};

Person.prototype.greeting = function() {
  console.log('Hi! I\'m ' + this.name.first + '.');
};

function Teacher(first, last, subject) {
  Person.call(this, first, last);

  this.subject = subject;
}

//Teacher.prototype = Person.prototype;
//Teacher.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);

Teacher.prototype.constructor = Teacher;
const t = new Teacher('John','Smith','Math');
```

**What would be the difference of using this?**

```
 Teacher.prototype = Person.prototype;


   or this


  Teacher.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
```

Comment: Do you really mean `Teacher.prototype.__proto__ = Person.prototype;`? That's quite strange. Do you mean `Teacher.prototype = Person.prototype;`?

Comment: sorry you are right. that's what i meant @CertainPerformance

Answer (score 1):

If you use the plain assignment method, changes to `Teacher.prototype` will also affect `Person.prototype`. This is not a good idea, because while a Teacher is a Person, a Person is not necessarily a Teacher:

```js
function Person(first, last) {
  this.name = {
    first,
    last
  };
};
Person.prototype.greeting = function() {
  console.log('Hi! I\'m ' + this.name.first + '.');
};
function Teacher(first, last, subject) {
  Person.call(this, first, last);

  this.subject = subject;
}

// Bad:
Teacher.prototype = Person.prototype;
// Because:
Teacher.prototype.teachesClass = () => true;
// Person.prototype now has that too:
const p = new Person();
console.log(p.teachesClass());
```

Now, both `.prototype`s are the same, so any mutations to one will affect the other. This is pretty much never what you want.

In contrast, when you use the `Object.create` method, assignments to `Teacher.prototype` will only affect `Teacher.prototype`. The object that `Teacher.prototype` inherits from, `Person.prototype`, will not be changed:

```js
function Person(first, last) {
  this.name = {
    first,
    last
  };
};
Person.prototype.greeting = function() {
  console.log('Hi! I\'m ' + this.name.first + '.');
};
function Teacher(first, last, subject) {
  Person.call(this, first, last);

  this.subject = subject;
}

// Good:
Teacher.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
// Because:
Teacher.prototype.teachesClass = () => true;
// Person.prototype does not have teachesClass
const p = new Person();
console.log(p.teachesClass);
```

Looking at the prototype chain:

```
Teacher.prototype = Person.prototype;
// You get:
Teacher.prototype <- Object.prototype
Person.prototype <- Object.prototype
Teacher.prototype === Person.prototype // (same object)

// Compare to
Teacher.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
// You get:
Teacher.prototype <- Person.prototype <- Object.prototype
```

Comment: ahhhh aha!! question. "If you use the plain assignment method, changes to Teacher.prototype will also affect Person.prototype." this is because it points to the same Object in memory?

Comment: Exactly, that's what's going on.